# How can i align a bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to align my bootstrap table but I cant. I want it like as bootstrap class 'd-flex justify-content-between'. if i have 3 items in my table ,I want 1st one in the left 2nd one middle and last one in the right side. but here it takes places by its own way.

code:

```
<table class="table table-striped text-center">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">product Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <tr key={product.id}>
            <td>{product.name}</td>
            <td>{product.price}</td>
            <td>
              <button className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: Please provide some code where you getting stuck.

Comment: code add on the description now.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to align the text in the `<td>` tags instead of the entire table.
You can add `text-left`, `text-center`, and `text-right` classes to your `<td>` tags, respectively or I would try this in your CSS:

```css
tr td:nth-child(1) {text-align: left;}
tr td:nth-child(2) {text-align: center;}
tr td:nth-child(3) {text-align: right;}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped text-center" border="1" style="width:100%;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">product Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{product.name}</td>
            <td>{product.price}</td>
            <td>
              <button className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```